# Grails config file returning empty object instead of string

Tags: grails, groovy, config

I am trying to read a string in from an external config file, but am for some reason only getting an empty object. Here is the config file `(DirectoryConfig.groovy)`

```
directory {
    logDirectory = "c:\\opt\\tomcat\\logs\\"
}
```

And the code that retrieves the directory (from a controller):

```
String dirName = grailsApplication.config.directory.logDirectory
File directory = new File(dirName)
```

For some reason, `dirName` always ends up being `"{}"`, and as a result the file cannot be read. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem - you should use / instead of \\ even with Windows; the JDK classes convert as needed. Only use \\ when writing to a file that will be read in Windows by a non-Java app

Answer (score 3):

Creating `DirectoryConfig.groovy` in your `grails-app/conf/` directory will not work by convention.

You should consider implementing solution that is recommended for externalizing Grails configuration - delivering `.groovy` or `.properties` files from classpath or filesystem. Take a look at commented code in `Config.groovy`:

```
// grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
//                             "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
//                             "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
//                             "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"]
```

It's very common way to provide configuration files that depend on runtime property:

```
// if (System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]) {
//    grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]
// }
```

I often use something like this (it's part of the `Config.groovy` file):

```
grails.config.locations = []
grails.project.config.type = "classpath"
grails.project.config.extension = "groovy"

environments {
    development {
        grails.project.config.file = "development-config.${grails.project.config.extension}"
    }
    test {
        grails.project.config.file = "test-config.${grails.project.config.extension}"
    }
}

if (System.properties["grails.config.type"]) {
    grails.project.config.type = System.properties["grails.config.type"]
}
if (System.properties["grails.config.file"]) {
    grails.project.config.file = System.properties["grails.config.file"]
}

grails.config.locations << "${grails.project.config.type}:${grails.project.config.file}"
```

By default it assumes that there is e.g. development-config.groovy file in the classpath, but I can simply change it by setting `-Dgrails.config.file=/etc/development.properties -Dgrails.config.type=file` in Java runtime so it uses `/etc/development.properties` file instead of the default one.

If you would like to run your example in the simplest way, you will have to do:

1) put your `DirectoryConfig.groovy` in the classpath source e.g. `src/java` (attention: it wont work if you put your file in `src/groovy`)

2) define in your `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.config.locations = [
        "classpath:DirectoryConfig.groovy"
]
```

3) re-run your application. `grailsApplication.config.directory.logDirectory` should now return the value you expect.

For more information about externalizing configuration go to http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized

Comment: Tried the three steps mentioned above, still ended up with the same value.